# Generic method issue

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to implement a LINQ-to-SQL extension method that will simply get a random row. This is my code:

```
public static T RandomRow(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int row = rand.Next(0, query.Count());
    return query.Skip(row).First();
}
```

Problem is, the query.Count() and query.Skip() have an error of 'The type arguments for method '...' cannot be inferred from usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly'. It works fine if I modify the T to be of a specific object, but it'd be great to use this method with any database object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the definition of the `T` generic parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method looks like it should be generic:

```
// Note the <T> after the method name
public static T RandomRow<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
```

Either that, or put it in a generic class.

You might also want to use the [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338725.aspx) method instead of `Skip`/`First`.

EDIT: As CodeInChaos notes, your use of `Random` is problematic too. See [my article on random numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for more information.

Comment: `T` could be defined as a type parameter, then it is not needed.

Comment: @leppie: Do you mean a type parameter of the class? If so, that's covered by my "or put it in a generic class". But I strongly suspect it *isn't* in a generic class.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks - bit of a silly mistake on my half. Thanks for the heads up on the Random issues - it's not crucial the numbers are completely random as it's going to be for a small game but I'll look into the cryptographic object

Comment: @Chris: "Not completely random" is one thing, but I suspect that getting the same number time and time again isn't ideal for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have another problem too: You create a new instance of `Random` on each call to this method. This means you will get the same result if you call it in quick succession, which breaks encapsulation.

You have several ways to avoid this problem:

1. Pass in an instance of `Random`, and have the calling code manage its life time
2. Use a static field containing an instance of `Random`. You'll need to take care of thread safety by either using locking or using a thread static field
3. Make it an instance method and make `Random` an instance field.
4. Use manual seeding with a better seed than the default seed.